# How to get only long and lat from address through googlemap's geocode API

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps, geocode

I am working on a project that involves getting the longitude and latitude of addresses using the googlemaps api. Curently, when I get the geocode of an address, I get all geocode of that adress, but I would only like to get the longitude and latitude. Is there anyway to do this within the googlemaps api?

```
import googlemaps

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='#####')

geocode_result = gmaps.geocode('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043')
print(geocode_result)
```

Currently when I run the script above, I get this result:

```
[{'address_components': [{'long_name': '1600', 'short_name': '1600', 'types': ['street_number']}, {'long_name': 'Amphitheatre Parkway', 'short_name': 'Amphitheatre Pkwy', 'types': ['route']}, {'long_name': 'Mountain View', 'short_name': 'Mountain View', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'Santa Clara County', 'short_name': 'Santa Clara County', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'California', 'short_name': 'CA', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'United States', 'short_name': 'US', 'types': ['country', 'political']}, {'long_name': '94043', 'short_name': '94043', 'types': ['postal_code']}], 'formatted_address': '1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA', 'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 37.4220578, 'lng': -122.0840897}, 'location_type': 'ROOFTOP', 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 37.4234067802915, 'lng': -122.0827407197085}, 'southwest': {'lat': 37.4207088197085, 'lng': -122.0854386802915}}}, 'place_id': 'ChIJtYuu0V25j4ARwu5e4wwRYgE', 'plus_code': {'compound_code': 'CWC8+R9 Mountain View, CA, USA', 'global_code': '849VCWC8+R9'}, 'types': ['street_address']}, {'address_components': [{'long_name': '1600', 'short_name': '1600', 'types': ['street_number']}, {'long_name': 'Amphitheatre Parkway', 'short_name': 'Amphitheatre Parkway', 'types': ['route']}, {'long_name': 'Mountain View', 'short_name': 'Mountain View', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'Santa Clara County', 'short_name': 'Santa Clara County', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'California', 'short_name': 'CA', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_1', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'United States', 'short_name': 'US', 'types': ['country', 'political']}, {'long_name': '94043', 'short_name': '94043', 'types': ['postal_code']}], 'formatted_address': '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA', 'geometry': {'location': {'lat': 37.4121802, 'lng': -122.0905129}, 'location_type': 'ROOFTOP', 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 37.4135291802915, 'lng': -122.0891639197085}, 'southwest': {'lat': 37.41083121970851, 'lng': -122.0918618802915}}}, 'place_id': 'ChIJVYBZP-Oxj4ARls-qJ_G3tgM', 'plus_code': {'compound_code': 'CW65+VQ Mountain View, CA, USA', 'global_code': '849VCW65+VQ'}, 'types': ['street_address']}]
```

But as I mentioned above, I would just like to get the location data, which in this case is: `{'location': {'lat': 37.4121802, 'lng': -122.0905129}`. Is there anyway to only request for this data with the googlemaps api, without having to use something such as a regex to get the long and lat? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex (unless of course you convert the data into a `str`, but why would you do that?).  Try this:

```
print([result['geometry']['location'] for result in geocode_result])
```